# django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry '22-add_' for key 'content_type_id'")

Tags: django-database, django-orm

I am using django multiple DB router concepts, having multiple sites with different db's. Base database user will login with all other sub sites.

When i try **syncdb** in base site its worked properly(at any time), but trying **syncdb** with other sites works first time only, if we try next time on-wards it throws integiry error like below

- **django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry
  '22-add_somesame' for key 'content_type_id'")**

Once i removed multiple DB router settings in that project means syncdb works properly(at any time).

So is this relates to multiple db router? or what else?

Please anyone advise on this, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is with the db router and django system objects. I've experienced the same issue with multiple DBs and routers. As I remember the problem here is with the auth.permission content types, which get mixed in between databases. The syncdb script otherwise tries to create these in all databases, and theb it creates permission content type for some object, which id is already reserved for a local model.

I have the following

```
BASE_DB_TYPES = (
 'auth.user',
 'auth.group',
 'auth.permission',
 'sessions.session',
```

)

and then in the db router:

```
def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
    if hasattr(model, '_meta') and str(model._meta) in BASE_DB_TYPES:
        return 'base_db' # the alias of base db that will store users
    return None # the default database, or some custom mapping
```

**EDIT**:

Also, the exception might say that you're declaring a permission '`add_somesame`' for your model '`somesame`', while Django automatically creates `add_`, `delete_`, `edit_` permissions for all objects.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the replay. I did the above things in my router file but same result. BASE_DB_TYPES is defined in top router file and de_for_read method updated with your code. Needs to do any other things?

Comment: This needs to be added in all routers. You should instruct the routers that these types will be *ONLY* created in 1 database(the master/auth).

Comment: In master site don't have any routers(no need in that), i have one sub site in that one router file available. My db_for_method is configured like :def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
   if hasattr(model, '_meta') and str(model._meta) in BASE_DB_TYPES:
      return 'usersandsessions'
        elif model._meta.app_label == 'auth':
            return 'usersandsessions'
        elif model._meta.app_label == 'accounts':
            return 'usersandsessions'
        elif model._meta.app_label == 'sessions':
            return 'usersandsessions'
        return None... remains the same.

Comment: Hmm.. do you define custom permissions for your models, i.e. model permission named "add_somesame" ? Django automatically creates such permission for all models - e.g. Model is "mymodel", then it will automatically create permissions "add_mymodel", "delete_mymodel", "edit_mymodel". If you try to create a permission with the same name - an error like this will occur. If this is not the case - you need to debug which exact model is causing the exception and to check where it is being created(in which DB), and to find out why a duplicate key is created.