# Django `auth` and `contenttypes` breaks syncdb

Tags: python, django, django-models, python-2.7

When I issue the command:

`python manage.py syncdb --database=mydb`

It shows the output as follows...

```
Creating tables ...
Creating table auth_permission
Creating table auth_group_permissions
Creating table auth_group
Creating table auth_user_user_permissions
Creating table auth_user_groups
Creating table auth_user
Creating table django_content_type
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 14, in <module>
    execute_manager(settings)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 459,     in execute_manager
    utility.execute()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 382,     in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 196, in     run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 232, in     execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 371, in     handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/syncdb.py",     line 110, in handle_noargs
    emit_post_sync_signal(created_models, verbosity, interactive, db)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/sql.py", line 189, in     emit_post_sync_signal
    interactive=interactive, db=db)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 172, in     send
    response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/__init__.py",     line 35, in create_permissions
    ctype = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(klass)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/contenttypes/models.py", line     42, in get_for_model
    defaults = {'name': smart_unicode(opts.verbose_name_raw)},
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 134, in     get_or_create
    return self.get_query_set().get_or_create(**kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 442, in     get_or_create
    return self.get(**lookup), False
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 361, in get
    num = len(clone)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 85, in     __len__
    self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 291, in     iterator
    for row in compiler.results_iter():
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 763,     in results_iter
    for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line     818, in     execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 40, in     execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line     337, in     execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: no such table: django_content_type
```

I have a custom db router that is basically set to django's example, except i have a custom attribute on MY models so that it knows which database they default to. `syncdb` works when in my `settings.py INSTALLED_APPS` I comment out: `django.contrib.auth` and `django.contrib.contenttypes`. Had this problem for a while, but have been putting it off until now, when I need to start on authentication. If you want my db router I'll post also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've explained a similar problem here: 
[django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry '22-add_' for key 'content_type_id'")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11207334/django-db-utils-integrityerror-1062-duplicate-entry-22-add-for-key-conte/11208118#11208118)

You don't need to comment out contrib.auth and contrib.contenttypes. Just make sure all django models - users, sessions, permissions are only used in 1 database, which could be considered as a master.

This will not directly solve your problem, but can be a starting point when dealing with multiple db's and db routers. What you need to know is that each model has it's content type in the database. 
The problem occur when django objects - user/session/permission are not restricted to a single database - then they are created into each database. And since a content-type makes a model unique, having content-types for a single type in multiple databases could lead to the problem explained in the other SO question above.

Answer (score 0):

In Django 1.4 you have to launch this command in the top-level folder of the project (path_to_project/you_project NOT path_to_project/you_project/you_project)

Comment: There's only one place you can call syncdb from, since it's based on the location of the `manage.py` file

Comment: Actually, you can run syncdb even in the inner folder. This is probably wrong but you can. If you use slqlite it creates new database; I don't know if this is a django 1.4 bug, but in my project it runs without complains.